Can I set a private sync word for LoRa-based systems?
I'm building a private network system with LoRa and ESP32 devices, where I have a couple of nodes and 1 gateway. I understand from the documentation and some examples that a sync word can be set to filter all packets that do not have it. which creates a private network.
However, I want to replicate my system in multiple places, where each "system" has its own private network.
Is this achievable by setting a private sync word for each system remotely?
In the end, I want to view the data of each private system via an application (that reads data from the cloud) per "registered" private network.
What is the way (if any) to register each couple of devices + gateway to a private network?

You mention LoRa but a gateway. Are you referring to LoRaWAN (hence the lorawan tag), which is a different beast, or are you actually using LoRa, and your "gateway" is a module collecting the data (and passing it along)?

yes, I'm building my own gateway, a LoRa device receiving data from LoRa nodes. I mentioned LoRawan since its similar in terms of system.

Well then, no LoRaWAN tag: LoRa and LoRaWAN are VERY different...

So now that we have ascertained which system you are using – LoRa – I can answer... You want to keep your network private, and there are different ways to achieve this.
Changing the sync word is one, although probably not the best idea – or at least not on its own. I have a few private networks running here, and I managed to keep them private – both in terms of my data staying private, and my devices not receiving outside data, as it can happen in crowded areas, with a mix of:

Unusual radio settings: Freq/SF/BW/CR are set to settings that are uncommon (not just for privacy but also performance).
Privacy itself is ensured by encryption. After all there is always the possibility that other devices end up with the same settings as yours. You lock the network by encrypting data. Even if other devices receive the data, there won't be any leakage.

Another important point to remember, and take care of, is that your "gateway" is probably single channel, which means that with several devices sending data, there could be interference. You should look into, and implement, Channel Activity Detection. This will ensure that data will actually be sent, and not lost due to another device sending at the same time.

somehow missed your answer, sorry for the delay. Thanks for your answer
However, this won't provide me the required, if I want to replicate my system multiple times, I need a private network per replication. Hence, I think I will use configuration packet per system everytime installed. those will provide me a capability to "set" ID remotely per system. I think

Setting a different password for each network will achieve just that.
